# Removing a class to a parent td element with a child button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a class to a parent td from a child button element thru jQuery. I can remove the class when the outer tr element is clicked with no problem but when trying to add the class back to the parent td it doesn't do anything. When debugging it seems to work. I am trying to do it without reloading the page hence the preventDefault method on the button click. Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

My html is this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<table id="order" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-header">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Order Number
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Project Number
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="click">
        <td id="orderNumber">
          1313
        </td>
        <td>
          50
        </td>
        <td id="td1313" class="hidden">
          <div class="verify-box">
            <div class="window">
              <button class="close">
                X
              </button>
              <span class="title">
                            Verify Order
                        </span>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                  <thead class="table-header">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        Item Number
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Item Description
                      </th>
                    </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center">
                    123456
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                    Description
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"     onclick="window.print()">
                Print
              </button>
             </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
 $('.click').on('click', function() {
  var $td = $(this).find('#orderNumber');
  var td = "#td" + $td.text().trim();
  $(td).removeClass('hidden');
 });

 // Closes verification window
 $('.close').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $td = $(this).closest('td');
  $td.addClass('hidden');
 });
```

I have also including fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/tspuq9vo/3/

Comment: .find() is for descendant searching, if the element you are clicking is below the element you are looking for then you need to use .closest().

Comment: You can use .parent() to move up the DOM also you can chain it, so you can say .parent().parent() for example

Comment: Instead of adding the class 'hidden' do .hide().   `$td.hide()`  Using `.show()` and `.hide()` generally work better for this kind of thing.

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique to the entire document, so if you have multiple rows in that table with `<td id="orderNumber">`, you're going to get some odd results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the click class on the tr causing it to get fired straight after the click event for the close button.

As a quick fix you can stop the click event from propagating by using

```js
 $('.click').on('click', function() {
     var $td = $(this).find('#orderNumber');
     var td = "#td" + $td.text().trim();
     $(td).removeClass('hidden');
 });

 // Closes verification window
 $('.close').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     var $td = $(this).closest('td');
     $td.addClass('hidden');
 });
```

Otherwise you should really only target the clickable td-s directly

Comment: Thank you that make sense... When clicking the td it is firing off the tr click!!!